# Is it possible to get full document revision history using the Drive API?

Tags: python-3.x, google-drive-api

I'm interested in getting the fully detailed revision history, which can be seen by hitting the "expand detailed version" drop-down button next to some revisions. I'm aware and able to pull full information on the combined revisions, but I'm trying to get a more detailed history of each document with as much granular edit information as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Revisions: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/revisions/list) and then the [Revisions: get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/revisions/get) to get all the details on the revision you selected.

The details you will get are listed on the [Revisions Resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/revisions#resource)

Comment: Thank you for the reply but like I stated in the question, I'm able to get details for top level revisions, what I can't seem to find resources for are the lower level revisions that we can see by clicking the arrow next to revisions in the document history list.

Comment: You can create a Feature Request on [Google Issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:191650) and ask for this to be implemented on the API.